# Pointers and Memory Address - Assault Cube

Tags: c++, pointers, reverse-engineering, cheat-engine

Will be using the game Assault Cube as an example. Here are the addresses found with Cheat Engine from searching the health value.

[image]

We have 0x0050F4F4 (static local player pointer) which points to 0x00CA9000 (dynamic player object address)

Then 0x00C9A000 + F8 = 0x00C9A0F8 will give us the dynamic address of health

Here is the class:

```
class CPlayer
{
public:
char __0x0000[0xF7]; //0x0 - 0xF7
    __int32 m_nHealth; //0xF8
};
```

```
#define ADDR_Player 0x0050F4F4

CPlayer* pPlayer = *(CPlayer**) ADDR_Player;

pPlayer->m_nHealth;
```

What I don’t understand is why did they cast ADDR_Player to a pointer to a pointer of type CPlayer? How is it a double pointer?

If you dereference *ADDR_Player:

0x0050F4F4 -> 0x00C9A000 = 13202112 (random value)

If you dereference *ADDR_Player + offset:

0x0050F4F4 -> 0x00C9A00+F8 = 40 (health)

I thought it would be like this:
`CPlayer* pPlayer = *(CPlayer*) ADDR_Player;` but this is incorrect and I don’t understand why the correct one is casted to a double pointer:

`CPlayer* pPlayer = *(CPlayer**) ADDR_Player;`

Comment: `char __0x0000[0xF7]; //0x0 - 0xF7` This looks weird. The array has `0xF7` elements `0x0 - 0xF6`. There may be another (padding) byte after that because the next member is `__int32`.

Comment: Are you asking why the programmers of Assault Cube stored a pointer to pointer to player at address 0x0050F4F4? That could have millions of answers that might all be wrong. Maybe they did just to confuse cheaters?

Answer (score 1):

`0x0050F4F4` is a memory address, so the type of a variable holding that value would be a "pointer to something", but a pointer to what?

What resides at address `0x0050F4F4`?  Another memory address: `0x00C9A000`.  Since that is a memory address, the type of that data is "pointer to something".  That means the type of the original variable holding `0x0050F4F4` is "pointer to pointer to something".

Finally, you can look at what resides at address `0x00C9A000`.  That's a `CPlayer` object, so the variable holding `0x00C9A000` is a "pointer to `CPlayer`" which means the variable holding `0x0050F4F4` is a "pointer to pointer to `CPlayer`".

That is, you have something like this in memory:

```
 Memory       ADDR_Player              0x0050F4F4               0x00C9A000
┌─────────────┬──────────┬─────────────┬──────────┬─────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│             │          │             │          │             │                        │
│     ...     │0x0050F4F4│     ...     │0x00C9A000│     ...     │     CPlayer Object     │
│             │     │    │             │     │    │             │                        │
└─────────────┴─────┼────┴─────────────┴─────┼────┴─────────────┴────────────────────────┘
                    │                  ▲     │                  ▲
                    │                  │     │                  │
                    └──────────────────┘     └──────────────────┘
```

As you can see, `ADDR_Player` points to a pointer that points to your `CPlayer` object.  That is, it is a `CPlayer**`.

Comment: So… 0x0050F4F4 points to 0x00C9A000. So are you saying 0x00C9A000 is a pointer aswell and not a variable? If that is the case then what memory address does 0x00C9A000 hold in its value?

Comment: Pointers _are_ variables.  At address `0x0050F4F4` is a `CPlayer*` variable with the value `0x00C9A000`.  That pointer points to a `CPlayer` object at address `0x00C9A000`.  See the diagram in my answer.  At the top are the addresses of the variables in memory, inside the boxes are the values held in those variables.

Answer (score 0):

You want a pointer `CPlayer*`. What will be a pointer when dereferenced is a pointer to pointer `CPlayer**`. So casting to `CPlayer**` and dereferencing is a good way to obtain `CPlayer*` value.